# Calling BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync() multiple times with different parameters

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I am trying to set up file uploading to a server.

I would like to divide the file into 'n' chunks of 'y' size each and then upload 'x' chunks at a time to the server using threads. 
When one of the 'x' chunks is completed then another chunk should start uploading until there are no more chunks left to upload.

I have been looking at BackgroundWorker and have the following implementation idea:

1) The following method to assign to Worker.DoWork

```
private void ChunkUploaderDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    //get arguments list form e.arguments and prepare next upload
    //The arguments list contains information such as next chunk number and chunk size etc..
    //Calculate file stream offset based on chunk size and upload the next y bytes.
}
```

2) I can then call

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += (obj, e) => WorkerDoWork();
worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler (Worker_ProgressChanged);
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler (Worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
worker.RunWorkerAsync(argumentsList);
```

With backgroundWorker, I can have it report progress as well and can also be notified about completion in order to start uploading the next chunk, so those are a couple of reasons why I would like to use it. The problem is that I am not sure if I should call worker.RunWorkerAsync() in the following manner (in case that I am uploading 4 chunks at a time):

```
worker.RunWorkerAsync(argumentsListForChunk1);
worker.RunWorkerAsync(argumentsListForChunk2);
worker.RunWorkerAsync(argumentsListForChunk3);
worker.RunWorkerAsync(argumentsListForChunk4);
```

And then when any of the worker completes and gives me a worker completed call back, then I can do this:

```
void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Check if we have any outstanding chunks and upload next chunk if available.
    //for example if we had chunk 5 next in line, then I could call RunWorkerAsync as follows:
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(argumentsListForChunk5);
}
```

I am relatively new to c# and would like to know if this is a good way to get things done.

My requirements, in a nutshell, are

1. Use threads to upload file chunks
2. Limit the number of threads
3. Keep a check for completed threads so that we can start uploading the next file chunk
4. Keep track of thread progress.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Edit::
The comments form @o_weisman and @HansPassant made me realize that the question was missing the following relevant information.
*I am trying to upload to a server that I control. The server limits connection speed and thus opening multiple connections for uploading file chunks will result in an over all speed boost.*

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to use more than one thread to upload the chunks? How do you benefit from dividing that task to multiple threads?

Comment: well, If i have a 10mb file, I can divide that file into 20 chunks of 0.5mb each, and then I can upload 4 chunks at a time by using 4 threads. when one of the chunks finishes uploading, i can go onto uploading the next chunk in line and so on. The chunks are combined together into a single file on the server. give me a speed bump when compared to uploading the whole 10mb in one go. :)

Comment: I didn't ask why you cut the files into chunks, just why not use one thread to upload the chunks sequentially

Comment: Having to buy 4 routers and Internet connections is the usual hangup with such an approach.  File servers typically defeat the same IP address starting more than one connection, a survival strategy.

Comment: @o_weisman : why would i cut the files into chunks if I wanted to upload them sequentially? i could just upload the whole file via one thread then. I am trying to upload multiple chunks 'simultaneously'.

Comment: @HansPassant : Yes, I agree. But, not if I am controlling the server (which I am) :)

Comment: @ShumaisUlHaq I'm simply doubting the fact that loading them 'simultaneously' would somehow boost upload speed. Unless of course the server (which we now know is controlled by you) limits each connection's bandwidth. If that is the case, then I think Jimbidf's answer is reasonable.

Comment: @o_weisman Right now I am trying to make it work with BackgroundWorker because moving to Tasks will mean having to start from scratch. But I am keeping an open mind here and will definitely look at Tasks too.

Comment: If u control the server then why not just remove connection speed limit.

Comment: @Blam The server connection speed is a requirement specification.

Comment: If server connection speed is a requirement specification then why are you doing all this work to violate that specifiction?

Comment: @Shumais can't you use multiple BackgroundWorker objects and have a manager class that spawns them and gets notified when any of them are done?

Comment: @o_weisman That is what I have in mind and am trying to get it done with that approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use BackgroundWorker for several concurrent operations.
It's meant to service the UI to do some single operation in the background and update the UI during or after the operation.

For several concurrent operations you better use Tasks.

1. Each task is *roughly* a different thread.

2. You can create as many as you like, but you can also use settings on the Task factory to limit the number of concurrent threads.

3. You can wait on tasks in several ways, either individually, or separately, or you can chain them together so that once one completes, the next one uses it's result and carries on.

4. Keeping track is always tricky. The background worker does provide a convenient way for this, because it's UI oriented. I'd recommend keeping one background worker alive to get continuous updates from some central state object.

this contains a pretty good explanation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx